# How to set up my Wordpress template structure for handling my custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, taxonomy

I'm having trouble setting up my Wordpress template. I'm not sure how to achieve the following. My website setup is the following:

I have a Custom Post Type "Chapter". A "Chapter" is parent to other CPT's. I have a few post types such as: reviews, interviews, blogposts, ...

On a chapter page I do a different WP_Query for every post type within this chapter.

[page template single-chapter.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBvNC.jpg)

Now I want to be able to click on "Blogpost (2)" and open an archive page of all blogpost within the current chapter. How can I achieve this? I assume I should create a template page "archive-blogpost.php". I already found that I can link to this page using:

```
<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'blogpost' ); ?>
```

However I can't see how this page could know in what chapter i'm currently in?

Comment: How do you make the connection between a chapter and a blogpost? Is it a category?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. It's not a category. A chapter is now a custom post type because it can have a "chapter subtitle" and an "chapter image". The CPT "Chapter" has a post relation and can have children "blogposts". You think it would better to use categories?

Comment: No not really, I just want to understand how you set up your CPT relationships. It could help if you paste in your question your CPT definitions.

Comment: I use a plugin WP types to define the custom post types. [WP-Types](https://wp-types.com/home/types-manage-post-types-taxonomy-and-custom-fields/).

Comment: I'm still able to change the setup in the backend. Is there a better way to define the relationsships?

Comment: The plugin WP Types has a function types_child_posts(); which returns all the child items of my chapter. However, my problem is that I want to create a link to an archive page. This archive page should list all these child post from that current chapter. I don't see how this template file could know, what chapter we are in? I'm guessing this is more like a basis Wordpress question?

Comment: I don't know much about WP Types so I can't really advice on this, but I just posted an answer that could work around. Not so sure about the last part, let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a WP types functions to achieve what I wanted:

$child_posts = types_child_posts("blogpost", array('post_id' => $_GET['wpv-pr-child-of']));

With this I can query all the child posts from the custom post type on a page.

I also use a session variable to keep track of the current chapter I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the WP Types plugin so far, but here is what you could do: add a chapter parameter to the archive link (with a rewrite rule for it), that you'll get in your blogposts archive template and display the posts conditionally to this parameter.

First we change the archive link to send the chapter slug:

```
<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'blogpost' ) . '/' . $post->post_name; ?>
```

Then we define in *functions.php* this new [rewrite tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag):

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%chapter%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

To make the URL looks good, we'll add a rewrite rule (so you don't have a url like `/archive/?chapter=chapter-1`, but `/archive/chapter-1`) - this still go to *functions.php*:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule($rules) {
    add_rewrite_rule('^archive/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=blogposts&chapter=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_filter('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

You may have to change the URL / post type name depending of your configuration.

And last, you can get this query arg in your blogposts archive template with `$wp_query->query_vars` array:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['chapter']
```

Since I don't know much about WP Types, I'm not really sure about what follows, but it seems you could query the childs posts of the chapter with this:

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['chapter']) && $chapter = get_page_by_path($wp_query->query_vars['chapter'])) {
    $childargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'blogposts',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(array('
            key' => '_wpcf_belongs_property_id', 'value' => $chapter->ID
        ))
    );
    $child_posts = get_posts($childargs);
} else {
    // default template : display all posts
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your well documented reply! I'll try this and get back to you.